# TS: null is not an array type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to conditionally add an object within an array of object.  When I am doing it, I get a TS error in my editor saying `{name: 'new', age:22} | null is not an array type`.  Even if I set `newAnimal` to type `any`, I still get that error.

```
const shouldAdd = true;

const newAnimal = {
   name: "new",
   age: 22,
}

const data = [
   {
     name: "dog",
     age: 11
   }, 
   ...(shouldAdd ? [newAnimal] : null),
   {
     name: "cat",
     age: 21,
   }
]
```

Comment: Type your `data` explicitly with something like `({name: string, age: number} | null)[]` or whatever time you actually need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to destructure `null` as an array. You'll need to use `[]` instead:

```js
const data = [
   {
     name: "dog",
     age: 11
   }, 
   ...(shouldAdd ? [newAnimal] : []),
   {
     name: "cat",
     age: 21,
   }
]
```